# Splitting a string with comma

Tags: javascript, string, split

Is there any way to split a string with comma `str.split(",")` will give same string?

Also `var t = str.split("#")`

let `#` be any character, then what is value of `t`?  I know `split()` returns an array.

Comment: Yes, the OP *should* specify a language, but clearly he's asking about JavaScript. Relax.

Comment: IMHO this looks like a homework question: "Let `#` be any character, then what is the value of `t`?"

Comment: it is javascript and it is not home work because javascript is not in our syllabu :D   ..But this problem arose when I am doing "home works " i8n javascript ...hi

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = str.split(",");
```

This will result in an array. The string representation is the array, joined by a comma (`,`). To turn this array in a string again, use the `array.join(separator)` function:

```
var str = arr.join(",");
```

Comment: thanks..but what about my first question?

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting"? Put each part on a separate line? In that case, use `separator="\n"` as in `arr.join("n")`.